# spring distcp creates target folder as filename

Tags: spring, hadoop, distcp, spring-data-hadoop

I am using spring `DistCp` to copy a file within hdfs. My code looks like this

```
distcp.copy(null, null, null, "/tmp",  null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
        new String[]{"/user/aq728y/publish/test.txt", "/user/aq728y/publish2/test.txt"});
```

In this case e.g. I want to copy the `test.txt` file from `publish` folder to `publish2` folder. Whether publish2 folder exists or not, what ends up happening is that distcp creates a folder called `publish2/test.txt` and then inside that folder it copies the `test.txt` file. So its ends up being `publish2/test.txt/test.txt`

If I use hadoop distcp directly I dont see this issue. Any idea why this is happening.

Comment: The second string must be the destination. Try `distcp.copy(null, null, null, "/tmp", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, new String[]{"/user/aq728y/publish/test.txt", "/user/aq728y/publish2"});`

Comment: I understand that will work but that's not how I want to do it. Mainly because I need to add a timestamp to the file name so it's more like `distcp file file-ts`. Specifying filename as target has worked for me in the past with spring distcp and it still works fine if I use the hadoop distcp command directly. Isn't spring distcp supposed to be a wrapper around it why does it works differently then

Comment: To clarify it further, if I use `hadoop distcp publish/test.txt publish2/test. txt` it works fine and doesn't creates a nested directory